# Eclipse can't parse heap dump

Tags: eclipse, memory, heap-memory, dump

When I try to open my .hprof file(800 MB), i get:

An internal error occurred during: "Parsing heap dump from 'D:\Workspace\Java\MemoryLeaks\java_pid9004.hprof'".

I tried to increase heap size up to -Xmx2048m, but this doesn't help.

Comment: I am getting 300 MB hhprof file and having Xmx = 1024m but still not able to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

**Eclipse MAT – Increasing Heap size**

If you are analyzing a heap dump of size, say 800 mb, allocate at least additional 800mb space for Eclipse MAT. If you can allocate more heap space, then it’s more the merrier. You can allocate additional heap space for Eclipse MAT tool, by editing **MemoryAnalyzer.ini** file. This file is located in the same folder where MemoryAnalyzer.exe is present. To the MemoryAnalyzer.ini you will add -Xmx1600m at the bottom.

Below is a sample MemoryAnalyzer.ini file with added -Xmx value:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library 
  plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-vmargs
-Xmx1600m
```

On the other hand, you may consider using other memory analysis tools such as: [HeapHero.io](http://heaphero.io/) and [JHat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jhat.html). However please be advised that JHat doesn’t work well with large size heap dumps and takes long time to load.

Answer (score 0):

800MB exactly? Are you sure there isn't more to the heapdump and you aren't just using a chunk of it?

Comment: 822109 KB , yes I'm sure that there isn't more

Comment: what process are you following to generate the heapdump?

Comment: try running jhat on the heapdump and see what that shows you.